# Symfony assets not found on local development

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm testing a pdf generated file with dompdf which generates it from html using twig previously. In that template I'm using:

```
<img style="width: 146px; height: 81px;" src="images/ticket/logo.png"/>
{{ absolute_url(asset('images/ticket/logo.png')) }}
```

The logo is not loading and the printed absolute url is: `http://localhost/images/ticket/logo.png`, the server is started at `localhost:8000` and I think the logo is not being found because of the port because when I hardcode the image url to `http://localhost:8000/images/ticket/logo.png` is found.

How can I tell symfony to look for these assets at this specific port? Or any other solution to get it working on my local machine too.

Comment: Why are you not using your absolute_url in the src part of your img ?

Comment: because it makes no difference, I still have the problem with the port

Comment: Where **exactly** did you configure Symfony in which way such that it knows that it should include a port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to edit the `framework.yaml` (you can edit the one of the environment in question, in this case, the test folder, so `config\packages\test\framework.yaml`) file and specify the `base_url`:

```
framework:
    assets:
        packages:
            images:
                base_urls: 'http://localhost:8000/images'
```

Then, using it on a twig template should be:
`asset('ticket/logo.png', 'images')`

Answer (score 1):

In my side, what i do is like this "src='/path-of-image'" and it works for me.
I didn't use "absolute_url"

Answer (score 0):

You could create an url with the port using **getSchemeAndHttpHost** and **getPort**

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}:{{ app.request.getPort() }}
```

Would return `http://localhost:8000`

So you can just do something like :

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() ~ ':' ~ app.request.getPort() ~ asset('images/ticket/logo.png') }}
```

And it should work, but you can check if app.request.getPort() return the proper port, or you could hard code it.

Comment: what is `app`? a KernelInterface?

Comment: symfony set a global template variable app in both Twig and PHP template engines by default, since you posted this question with the Symfony tag I believe it si appropriate to your need, is it working ?

Comment: not working, that's why I though I had to pass it: `Twig\Error\RuntimeError: Impossible to invoke a method ("getSchemeAndHttpHost") on a null variable.`. Could be because I'm generating the pdf from a test case.

Comment: Oh right, you do not have a request from a test case, i'm gonna try a few things when I get home and may post some result if they are interesting for this post